# View does not contain the user which send a request

Tags: python, django

I created a view for payment verification, but after the payment, even when I logged in before, it returned an anonymous user.

How can I edit my code to include the user who sends the request?

```
def verify(request, *args, **kwargs):
    order_id = kwargs['order_id']
    open_order: Order = Order.objects.filter(
        Q(user=request.user.id) & Q(is_paid=False)).first()
    total_price = int(open_order.total_price())
    t_status = request.GET.get('Status')
    t_authority = request.GET['Authority']
    req = None
    if request.GET.get('Status') == 'OK':
        req_header = {"accept": "application/json",
                      "content-type": "application/json'"}
        req_data = {
            "merchant_id": MERCHANT,
            "amount": total_price,
            "authority": t_authority
        }
        req = requests.post(url=ZP_API_VERIFY, data=json.dumps(
            req_data), headers=req_header)
        if len(req.json()['errors']) == 0:
            t_status = req.json()['data']['code']
            if t_status == 100:
                order = Order.objects.get_queryset().get(id=order_id)
                order.is_paid = True
                order.refrence_id = req.json()['data']['ref_id']
                order.authority_id = t_authority
                order.pay_date = datetime.now()
                order.save()
                context = {
                    'verification_successful': True,
                    'reference_id': str(req.json()['data']['ref_id']),
                    'orderID': order_id,

                }
                return render(request, 'eshop_cart/verify.html', context)

            elif t_status == 101:
                context = {
                    'verification_successful': False,
                }
                return render(request, 'eshop_cart/verify.html', context)
            else:
                context = {
                    'verification_successful': False,
                }
                return render(request, 'eshop_cart/verify.html', context)
        else:
            e_code = req.json()['errors']['code']
            e_message = req.json()['errors']['message']
            return HttpResponse(f"Error code: {e_code}, Error Message: {e_message}")
    else:
        context = {
            'verification_successful': False,
            'order_id': order_id,
        }
        return render(request, 'eshop_cart/verify.html', context)
```

How can I edit this code to have a user ID in it, thanks for helping.

Comment: I think, the payment verification request is NOT started from the browser, but from the payment system. This will issue a request without any user data (without cookies, etc). The payment system offer normally a way to specify URL and credentials (http auth basic) to be used. The payment data (amount, person identifier, order number, etc.) should be included.

Comment: Where do you want to put the user id ? In the order object ? Please share us your models.py